# Immitating a global list in Haskell to generate a unique random value

Tags: haskell, random, global, monads, mutable

I'm currently building a toy meal planning application and have decided to write the back-end in Haskell simply to challenge myself. The problem that I'm having is described in the title in which I believe I need some global, mutable list in which to record previous requests (they are not made at the same time). This is the route that is particularly in question, specifically where random_value is bound:

```
getMeal :: Pipe -> ScottyM ()
getMeal pipe = post "/get_meal/:mid?" $ do
    mid <- rescue (param "mid" :: ActionM Int) (\_ -> return 0)
    doc <- access pipe master "risto" $ do
        meal_count <- count $ select [] "meals"
        random_value <- getStdRandom (randomR (0, meal_count - 1))
        if mid == 0
            then findOne $ select ["id" =: random_value] "meals"
            else findOne $ select ["id" =: mid] "meals"
    case doc of
        Nothing -> text "Meal not found"
        Just a -> json $ Meal (at "id" a) (at "name" a) (at "calories" a) (at "yield" a) (at "ingredients" a)
```

However, as you can imagine, if this function is called 5 separate times, it may generate the same value for the meal. In an imperative language, I would initialize a queue with a limit of 5 items and be done with it. Exploration has led me to believe that the State monad is likely where I should be looking, and after some experimentation, I came up with:

```
type GetState = [Int]

pushLast :: Int -> State GetState ()
pushLast v = state $ \(x:xs) -> ((), if length xs == 5 then v:init xs else v:xs)

checkLastFive :: Int -> State GetState Bool
checkLastFive v = state $ \xs -> (elem v xs, xs)
```

I thought that this might be over-complicating it, so I also came up with:

```
pushLastGet :: Int -> State [Int] ()
pushLastGet n = do
    s <- Control.Monad.State.get
    if elem n s
        then return ()
        else Control.Monad.State.put (n:s)
```

The major problem that I'm having is a struggling with trying to solve this imperatively. I'm imagining something along the lines of (in Haskell/Python-like pseudocode):

```
while True:
    random_value <- getStdRandom (randomR (0, meal_count - 1))
    if pushLastGet random_value != (): -- value was not in list
        break
```

Furthermore, I'm struggling to fully grasp exactly *where and how* an initial state should be initialized, and what exactly my logic looks like in Haskell and further within the constraints of the monads that wrap it.

I've also had the thought that there might be a clever non-monadic way of doing this perhaps using `until`, but my knowledge level is not quite there yet.

Comment: `getStdRandom` generates a random number "imperatively", or rather much in the same way any other `IO` function works. You are not worried that calling `getLine` 5 times will return 5 identical lines. Or are you?

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. I understand that the random number is generated imperatively (as my main calls initStdGen first). If getMeal is called 5 times from the client, you could get the following generated ids [1,4,7,3,7] initially representing Monday to Friday; this implies that the same meal will have been randomly chosen for both Wednesday and Friday (which I do not want).

Comment: Oh you want to generate random numbers without repetition. You may want be interested in a basic example of a stateful Scotty application https://github.com/scotty-web/scotty/blob/master/examples/globalstate.hs, but I think this is an overkill, you probably should keep this state in a cookie as this is a small per-user state. Or, alternatively, keep a real database with user data including this state (if you don't want the state to be lost when the user connects from a different computer, or your server is restarted).

Comment: Isn't this just a situation for an MVar?

Comment: @Carl the example I linked uses a TVar from Control.Concurrent.STM rather than an MVar, because of concurrent nature of web services. In a more normal app an MVar seems fine.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. MVars are designed for concurrent access. TVars are for *transactional* concurrent access, which doesn't seem relevant here.